# Visual Studio Team Services is there an icon to notify when files have been updated

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am using VS2012 with TFS on a server workspace.

When someone checks something out a person icon is shown next to the file so you know it is currently locked by someone else, however when they check it back in the icon changes back to a lock icon without any indication that the files has been updated.

Is there a setting i'm missing that will show that you don't have the latest file maybe an icon next to the file in the solution explorer?

The only way i see how to do it is to view history on each file or go to the source control explorer and run a compare on every files, both of these options are not very efficient as I would not know when to perform this so i would have to do it on every check out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you did not miss any particular detail. After the checkin, the icon returns to a lock, and there are no notifications by default.

I believe that there is nothing that can be done about the padlock icon, but you can set up alerts (e-mail) to be triggered when check-ins are made.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx) and [here (alerts for specific folders)](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/11/21/how-to-setup-tfs-check-in-alerts-for-specific-folders-in-visual-studio-2008-and-2010/) to understand how to configure e-mail alerts using TFS Event Service.

You can also [bind notifications to workitems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181334.aspx).

If your TFS is configured to use [gated-checking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx#team_impact) to perform a build on a "build server" before each check-in, you can subscribe to the [Team Foundation Build Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to receive notifications of new builds that were queued/processed on the server.

Hope it helps.